# How can I upload and send Images to server using webservices without using Base 64 encoded string in Android?

Tags: php, android, image, web-services, base64

How can I send images (may be small or big sizes) using Webservices without using Base 64 in Android?

I had worked on Base 64 and could be able to display the images in server.

Is there any other possibilities than using Base 64 to send an Images using webservices in Android?

Comment: you can user Apache common library for uploading image.

Comment: @Nasser- Apache common lib in webservices ??

Comment: actually i am not remembering name of that package but they are in my projects libs folder as httpclient-4.2.3.jar,httpcore-4.2.2.jar,httpmime-4.2.3.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
      final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      File file = new File(path_to_your_image);
      final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        final byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
        int n;
        while ((n = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
          out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
      final byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
      String urlString = "http://ip_address/your_php";
      HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(urlString);
      postRequest.setEntity(new  ByteArrayEntity(data));
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest);
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

..and i've used apache lib as.

in My threads doInBackground() method:

```
@Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {                    
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", photosURLString));
            LogMsg.d("Photo "+photosURLString);
            if (loactionID != null){
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LocationID", loactionID));
                LogMsg.d("teamID "+loactionID);
            }
            if (businessID != null){
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BusinessID", businessID));
                LogMsg.d("BusinesID "+businessID);
            }
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID", userID));
            LogMsg.d("userID "+userID);

            post(ActivityUploadPhotos.this.getString(R.string.image_upload), nameValuePairs);

            return null;
        }
```

and here's the post method.

```
 public void post(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        for(int index=0; index < nameValuePairs.size(); index++) {
            if(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("photo")) {
                // If the key equals to "image", we use FileBody to transfer the data
                entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), new FileBody(new File (nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue()) ,"image/jpeg" ));
            } else {
                // Normal string data
                entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), new StringBody(nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue()));
            }
        }
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        LogMsg.d(""+response);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```